# How to exclude imported URL parameters when they have no value?

Tags: paw-app

I've installed the Swagger Importer, which is just great.  It saved a lot of setup time.  It also enumerated all of our APIs optional parameters, which is also good because I don't have to reference docs; however, I don't want GET and POST requests to send the params when I haven't explicitly set the values.  Is there a way to configure PAW to not send URL Params when they have no value?  One option is to just duplicate an item and then prune the list, but it seems reasonable that there should be a way to simply ignore items that aren't set.

For example:
Don't GET:
http://domain.com/api/v1/users?maxResultCount=&isActive=true
(because maxResultCount is optional and not set)
Instead, do GET:
http://domain.com/api/v1/users?isActive=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release, Paw Version 3.0.7 (Retail) now provides checkboxes on URL parameters.